# Comparison of empirical distributions in ciruclar/polar coordinates

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test, circular-statistics, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I have 4 sets of 24 measurements of a polar variable (univariate). I want to use a statistical test, like the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, to test whether said sets differ significantly from each other.

My questions:

- Is the K-S test suitable for this type of data?
- Is the K-S test suitable for sets of this size?
- If yes to the above, how is the K-S test defined mathematically for polar distributions?
- If no to the above, which test is suitable, is there an existing implementation in R or python, or a mathematical description so I can implement it myself?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are specific extensions for such comparisons for circular data. Kolmogorov-Smirnov is not applicable because it is not rotationally invariant.

Comment: I chose the Watson test, namely watson.two.test() from the R package circular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, I found that the [Watson test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93von_Mises_criterion#Watson_test)  is needed in this case.